# How to return null when element is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm converting an xml string to a table type:

```
SELECT
[Guid] = r.value('(Guid)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
[Id] = r.value('(Id)[1]', 'int'),
[SomeColumn] = r.value('(SomeColumn)[1]', 'int'),
FROM
@xml.nodes('//Items') AS T(r)
```

Where `SomeColumn` is a nullable int. The xml that is passed is the following for this element:

```
<SomeColumn xsi:nil="true" />
```

However, the column is set to 0 instead of null. Is there a way to enforce to return null on nullable columns that are actually null?

Comment: Can we have a *minimal* but *complete* sample piece of XML that the above query can be run against please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can retrieve it as `varchar` instead of `int` and then check for emptiness of retrieved string something like:

```
SELECT
    [Guid] = r.value('(Guid)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
    [Id] = r.value('(Id)[1]', 'int'),
    [SomeColumn] = cast(nullif(r.value('(SomeColumn)[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '') as int)
FROM
    @xml.nodes('//Items') AS T(r)
```